# Add custom button to the changeset status in the Customizer

Tags: plugins, actions, theme-customizer, publish

I would like to add custom button to changeset_status in the Customizer actions. Any idea how can I do that?

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no official hook for customizer actions yet. Since the customizer actions are predefined by javascript, you can use the [The Customizer JavaScript API](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/the-customizer-javascript-api/) to add new actions via the `push` function.

PHP function for the index.php/functions.php:

```
    // Include scripts in customizer.
    add_action( 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts', 'script' );
        
    function script() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-customize-controls', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'customizer.js', [], null, true );
    }
```

and the framework customizer.js file...

```
;(function (api) {
    api.bind('ready', function () {
        api.settings.changeset.statusChoices.push({"status":"action","label":"Action"});
    });
})(wp.customize);
```

Does this option work for you?